# My itunes sales report is not correct when it compare with Financial Reports

Tags: itunes, app-store-connect, itunes-store

Every month i download sales report from itunes using their java library. And this data is saved in to my database.

Report contain number of fields and i used to save **developer_proceeds** field as my earnings. But when i look in to the Financial report there is a big difference in amount. For this reason i double check my report. First i look Sales report from march. after i check this from 'Payments and Financial Reports' Earnings tab. But this report contain some extra contents.

if anyone know about this please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Are you applying international exchange rates to your developer_proceed field?  That could account for a big difference in amount.

If you're doing the exchange rate conversions, there would still be a small difference as the exchange rates change a lot, and will most likely have been different from when the Sales report was created and you converted it vs. when Apple converts the numbers to cut your check.